# Meaning of "grant to somebody that..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "grant to us that..." in this context mean? It is from the Christian Bible, from Luke 1:72-74:

> <sup>72</sup>He will do this to show mercy to our fathers and to remember his holy covenant, <sup>73</sup>the oath that he swore to Abraham our father, **to grant to us** <sup>74</sup>that we, having been delivered out of the hand of our enemies, would serve him without fear. (Luke 1:72-74)

Answer (score 1):

A grant is a formal gift. We could simplify the sentence by removing all the explanatory clauses and get something like this:

> He will do this to keep his promise to give us the ability to serve him without fear